# undefined function geoip_asnum_by_name

Tags: php, geoip

Having some issues with this particular function, `geoip_country_name_by_name` works fine.  I'm running php5.5 installed via apt, have installed php5-geoip libgeoip-dev geoip-database.  Also tried:

```
wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
sudo mkdir -v /usr/share/GeoIP
sudo mv -v GeoLiteCity.dat /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat
```

**NOTE** I'm running Ubuntu.

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question so it would be easier to understand. The error simply says that the function undefined - doesn't exist in the library you've installed. Or you're writing the function's name wrong or it really doesn't exist in the library.

Comment: I think this function must not exist in the php5-geoip library if thats the case? it is specified as one of the geoip functions on php.net. 

The spelling im using is the same as in the error showin in the subject line, im using:

$asn = geoip_asnum_by_name('nufc.com');

Comment: According to the docs the requirement is `(PECL geoip >= 1.1.0)`.
I guess the library isn't installed or it might be an older version?

Comment: Thanks for your help Ofir, yes looks like this could be some kind of pecl issue, i tried removing php5-geoip via apt and then installing using pecl install geopip and gotthe following:

could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/geoip-1.0.8.tgz"
Download of "pecl/geoip" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/geoip"

Maybe a php5.5 thing? might try a compiled version of 5.4 unless you have any other suggestions?